# How can I find Alphanumeric in a string

Tags: php, javascript, regex

```
$foo = "username122";

pre_match('Contain only aplhanumeric string', $foo){
   return true;
}
```

`$foo` Contain Only alphanumeric not special characters `(=\*-[`( etc)

Comment: The tags were added to actually tag the question or are you just trying to get some attention?

Answer (score 4):

`ctype_alnum()` function will do you dandy :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression matching on alphanumeric characters only from beginning to end:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/
```

For example:

```
$testRegex = "/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/";
$testString = "abc123";
if (preg_match($testRegex, $testString)) {
    // yes, the string is entirely alphanumeric
} else {
    // no, the string is not entirely alphanumeric
}
```

Comment: `$testString = @"abc123";`  - why the `@`?

Comment: @hakre - Well we don't want any errors raising when assigning a string now, do we? :D

Comment: @webnoob: Well the `@` does not cover the assignment. ;)

Comment: @hakre - Ah yes, I guess not. I guess it's just there to give us something to talk about then :)

Comment: Let's see :) I made the answer more complete adding it to the first assignment line, too.

Comment: Please don't make playful edits to people's answers. Inquiring why something was done is perfectly acceptable though, especially in this case.

Comment: Whoops, the `@` was there by mistake: I'm currently developing an iOS app on my other screen and that's how you create a string in Objective-C :) Habit..

Comment: isn't it missing star at the end ? like this `/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/`

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression for something like this won't change between PHP and JavaScript. In JavaScript it's an object, whereas in PHP it's a string, but the pattern is still the same:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

Where `^` represents the start of the string and `$` represents the end of the string. Next, `a-z` matches any letter, and `0-9` matches any number. The `+` states that the previous pattern could be repeated one or more times. The `i` modifier makes the `a-z` portion case-insensitive, so upper and lower case are matched.

Testing in JavaScript:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test("Foo123"); // true
```

Testing in PHP:

```php
preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+$/i", "Foo123"); // 1
```

With PHP, you have the option of using POSIX character classes, such as `:alnum:`. Please note that this won't work in JavaScript:

```
preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]]+$/i", "Foo123"); // 1
```

There's actually a much easier method for testing in PHP, using the [Ctype functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ctype.php), specifically the [`ctype_alnum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) function, which will return a boolean value stating whether all characters in a given string are alphanumeric or not:

```
ctype_alnum("Foo123"); // true
ctype_alnum("Foo!23"); // false
```

Comment: thanx itz working when i put $foo = "username123?*-="
it gives me desire error but when i gives $foo = "username123?*-=\"
it not gives me erroe...

Comment: A value of `username123?` will fail. And `\"` will raise issues in both JavaScript and PHP unless your `\` is further escaped.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match('~[^a-z0-9 ]~i', $foo)) {
//DO SOMETHING HERE;
}
```